# How can I add comments in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, comments

I want to add comment in SQL code. How can I do this? I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

Several ways:

```
# Comment
-- Comment
/* Comment */
```

Remember to [put the space after `--`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435989/mysql-is-not-supporting-single-line-comments-here-what-would-be-the-reason).

See [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html).

Comment: [Remember to put the space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14435989/632951) after `--`

Comment: Is there any general best practice or style guideline for when to use these different syntaxes? Obviously the last one is ideal for multi-line comments, but is there any rule of thumb for single-line comments?

Comment: @StockB no, but it never hurts to be consistent with your coding styles.

Answer (score 34):

"A comment for a column can be specified with the `COMMENT` option. The comment is displayed by the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW FULL COLUMNS` statements. This option is operational as of MySQL 4.1. (It is allowed but ignored in earlier versions.)"

As an example

```
--
-- Table structure for table 'accesslog'
--

CREATE TABLE accesslog (
aid int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'unique ID for each access entry', 
title varchar(255) default NULL COMMENT 'the title of the page being accessed',
path varchar(255) default NULL COMMENT 'the local path of teh page being accessed',
....
) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP was asking for.

Comment: It's what I was looking for :) Incidentally, I found the COMMENT argument had to be before any AFTER argument; order is important, evidently.

Answer (score 21):

You can use single-line comments:

```
-- this is a comment
# this is also a comment
```

Or a multiline comment:

```
/*
   multiline
   comment
*/
```

Comment: The `#` form is not accepted by [the syntax highlighter here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) ("`lang-sql`"). Is it the syntax highlighter's fault or is that form special for MySQL?

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html) you can use:

```
#  For single line comments
-- Also for single line, must be followed by space/control character
/*
    C-style multiline comment
*/
```

Comment: The `#` form is not accepted by [the syntax highlighter here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) ("`lang-sql`"). Is it the syntax highlighter's fault or is that form special for MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

```sql
/* comment here */
```

Here is an example:

```sql
SELECT 1 /* this is an in-line comment */ + 1;
```

Reference: *[9.7 Comments](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comments.html)*

Answer (score 1):

Three types of commenting are supported:

1. Hash base single line commenting using #

   ```
   Select * from users ; # this will list users
   ```
2. Double Dash commenting using `--`

   ```
   Select * from users ; -- this will list users
   ```

   Note: It's important to have single white space just after `--`
3. Multi line commenting using /* */

   ```
   Select * from users ; /* this will list users */
   ```