# MySQL is not supporting single line comments here. What would be the reason?

Tags: mysql, command-line, comments

Here is what I am getting when I use single line comment (using **--**):

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax

Actually I am using these comments in a procedure to show what exactly a line does. Then I checked directly at the MySQL command line, but I got this error:

```
mysql> select 1;--test select
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

    -> ;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '--test select' at line 1
```

Do I need to configure a file to support this? It is working fine if I use multi-line comments (using `/* Something */`).

I googled and went through MySQL documentation. In that it has shown me it supports ( **--** ).
What could be the error?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From MySQL documentation:

> From a “-- ” sequence to the end of the line. In MySQL, the “-- ” (double-dash) comment style requires the second dash to be followed by
>   at least one whitespace or control character (such as a space, tab,
>   newline, and so on).

You need some space character after `--`, for example:

```
mysql> select 1;-- test select
```

Answer (score 7):

Your syntax is wrong - read about [comment syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html).

Just add a space after `--`:

```
mysql> select 1; -- test select
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```