# sql newbie gets sql error, dont know why

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

This is my sql query:

```
CREATE TABLE items(
id int(3) ,
name VARCHAR(255) ,
amount INT(4),
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

 -- BRONIE DO WALKI WRĘCZ
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('1', 'KATANA','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('2', 'HATCHET','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('3', 'TACTICAL KNIFE','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('4', 'MACHETE','0');

 -- PISTOLETY
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('5', '1911','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('6', 'B92','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('7', 'B93R','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('8', 'DESERT EAGLE','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('9', 'FN FIVESEVEN','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('10', 'SIG SAUER P226','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('11', 'STI Eagle Elite .45 ACP','0');

 --  STRZELBY
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('12', 'AA-12','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('13', 'KT DECIDER','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('14', 'MOSSBERG 590','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('15', 'SAIGA','0');

 -- KARABINY SZTURMOWE
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('16', 'AK-74M','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('17', 'AKM','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('18', 'FN SCAR CQC','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('19', 'FN SCAR NIGHT STALKER','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('20', 'G36','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('21', 'IMI TAR-21','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('22', 'M16','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('23', 'M4','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('24', 'M4 Semi','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('25', 'MASADA','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('26', 'SIG SAUER 556','0');

 -- KARABINY SNAJPERSKIE
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('27', 'BLASER R93','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('28', 'M107','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('29', 'MAUSER SP66','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('30', 'MAUSER SRG DESERT','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('31', 'SVD','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('32', 'VSS VINTOREZ','0');

 -- SUB MACHINE GUNY
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('33', 'BIZON','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('34', 'EVO-3','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('35', 'FN P90','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('36', 'FN P90 S','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('37', 'HONEY BADGER','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('38', 'MP5/10','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('39', 'MP7','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('40', 'UZI','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('41', 'VERESK SR-2','0');

 -- LIGHT MACHINE GUNY
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('42', 'FN M249','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('43', 'PKM','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('44', 'RA H23','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('45', 'RPK-74','0');

  -- AMMO
-- ARROWS 
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('46', 'ARROW', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('47', 'EXPLOSIVE ARROW', '0');
--HANDGUN AMMO
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('48', '9MM MAG', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('49', '.45 ACP STI EAGLE ELITE', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('50', '5.7 FN M240 MAG', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('51', 'DESERT EAGLE AMMO', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('52', '9X19 PARA MAG', '0');
--SHOTGUN AMMO
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('53', '2X 12 GAUGE', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('54', 'SHOTGUN SHELL 2X', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('55', 'SHOTGUN SHELL 8X', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('56', 'SAIGA 10', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('57', '12 GAUGE SLUG', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('58', 'AA-12 DRUM', '0');
--ASSAULT RIFLE AMMO
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('59', 'SG 30 ROUND', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('60', '5.45 AK 30', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('61', '5.45 AK 45', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('62', '5.45 AK DRUM', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('63', '7.62 AKM CLIP', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('64', 'STANAG 30', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('65', 'STANAG 45', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('66', 'STANAG 60', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('67', 'STANAG C-MAG', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('68', 'G36 AMMO', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('69', 'G36 C-MAG', '0');
--SMG AMMO
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('70', 'SMG-20', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('71', 'SMG-40', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('72', 'MP5 10MM MAG', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('73', 'CZ SCORPION EVO-3 AMMO', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('74', 'MP7 30', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('75', 'MP7 40', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('76', 'P90 50 ROUNDS', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('77', 'BIZON 64 AMMO', '0');
--SNIPER RIFLE AMMO
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('78', '.308 WINCHESTER', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('79', 'SVD AMMO', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('80', 'VSS-10', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('81', 'VSS-20', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('82', 'AWM .338 MAGNUM AMMO', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('83', '.50 BMG', '0');
--LIGHT MACHINE AMMO
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('84', 'M249 AMMO BOX', '0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('85', 'PKM AMMO BOX', '0');

 -- ATACZMENTY
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('86', 'ACOG','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('87', 'BLACKWATER LONG RANGE','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('88', 'COMPACT SCOPE','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('89', 'FLASH HIDER','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('90', 'FORWARD GRIP','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('91', 'HOLOGRAPHIC','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('92', 'PSO-1','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('93', 'PISTOL FLASHLIGHT','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('94', 'PISTOL LASER','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('95', 'RED DOT SP','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('96', 'REFLEX SIGHT','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('97', 'RIFLE FLASHLIGHT','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('98', 'RIFLE LASER','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('99', 'SMG GRIP','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('100', 'SMG GRIP 2','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('101', 'SILENCER','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('102', 'SWISS ARMS SCOPE 8X','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('103', 'TACTICAL SNIPER SCOPE','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('104', 'RPK-74','0');

 -- MISC
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('105', 'FRAG GRENADE','0');
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('106', 'COMPUND CROSSBOW','0');
```

(I can't really post error output image so here's a link:)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIVjT.png

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '--HANDGUN AMMO
INSERT INTO items (id, name, amount) VALUES ('48', '9MM MAG', '0' at line 1**

Comment: maybe it's stupid, but when writing comments, leavve a space between the two dashes and the comment: '-- your comment'. Try it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql is not supporting single line comments here. What would be the reason.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435989/mysql-is-not-supporting-single-line-comments-here-what-would-be-the-reason)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to write the comment `--` must be followed by a white space.

see more in the [MySQL manual - 9.6 Comment Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html)

BTW, you have the same problem in other lines:

- `--HANDGUN AMMO` change to `-- HANDGUN AMMO`
- `--SHOTGUN AMMO` change to `-- SHOTGUN AMMO`
- `--ASSAULT RIFLE AMMO` change to `-- ASSAULT RIFLE AMMO`
- `--SMG AMMO` change to `-- SMG AMMO`
- `--SNIPER RIFLE AMMO` change to `-- SNIPER RIFLE AMMO`
- `--LIGHT MACHINE AMMO` change to `-- LIGHT MACHINE AMMO`

Answer (score 1):

The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html) specifies a space between the dashes and the comment:

```
-- HANDGUN
```

Note that 'Shotgun', 'SMG', etc will also fail, so you'll have to adjust those comments as well.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I notice is that you have allot of code that doesnt need to be there. Why not do a insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO items 
    (id, name, amount)
VALUES
    ('48', '9MM MAG', '0'),
    ('49', '.45 ACP STI EAGLE ELITE', '0'),
    ('50', '5.7 FN M240 MAG', '0'),
    ('51', 'DESERT EAGLE AMMO', '0'),
    ('52', '9X19 PARA MAG', '0');
```

As for why it was throwing the error, I cant see why it was. Another thing that you might want to consider is creating a separate table for ammo and another for weapons and another for misc items. You would then want to create a master table that would list weapons with the possible ammo. Doing so would make your schema allot easier to read and manage.

Comment: that's really useful anwser, i will keep it in mind. thank you!