# A rudimentary way to store comments on a proposal webpage using SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am a software engineer, but I am very new to databases and I am trying to hack up a tool to show some demo.

I have an [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) server which serves a simple web page full of tables. Each *row* in the table has a proposal *id* and a *link* to a web page where the proposal is explained. So just two columns.

```
----------------------
|  id    |  proposal |
|--------------------
|  1     |  foo.html |
|  2     |  bar.html |
----------------------
```

Now, I want to add a third column titled *Comments* where a user can leave comments.

```
------------------------------------------------
|  id    |  proposal |  Comments               |
|-----------------------------------------------
|  1     |  foo.html | x: great idea !         |
|        |           | y: +1                   |
|  2     |  bar.html | z: not for this release |
------------------------------------------------
```

I just want to quickly hack up something to show this as a demo and get feedback. I am planning to use SQLite to create a table per id and store the userid, comments in the table. People can add comment at the same time. I am planning to use lock to perform operations on the SQLite database. I am not worried about scaling just want to show and get feedback. Are there any major flaw in this implementation?

[There are similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098655/how-can-i-add-comments-in-mysql). But I am looking for a simplest possible implementation.

Comment: What is your question? how to create comments; how to create a comment field/column; what is the best implementation for a website that includes user comments (which is way too broad and opinionated); or something else?

Comment: my question is How to implement comments for a web page using sqlite ?

Comment: That of course is hard to say without knowing more about your data etc, but you seem to have a incrementing integer field and that is an obvious candidate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table per ID; why would you want to do that? If you get a large number of proposals, the number of tables can get out of hand very quickly. You just need to keep an id column in the table to keep track of things and keep the number of tables in a sane figure.

The other drawback of using a table for each proposal is that you will not be able to use prepared statements for those, because table names cannot be bound as a parameter.

Comment: how will I have one to many relationship and query without a full table scan ? If i have a single table where all comments on all proposal sit how can I easily get comments only for proposal I need without doing a full table scan ?

Comment: That is where indexes come into the picture. When you have a proper index only the relevant records are read.

Comment: what will be the primary key of the table that has the comments ?

Comment: Index solved the problem of searching just the relevant records

Answer (score 0):

SQLite assumes the table name is 'a'

#### Add column

`alter table a add column Comments text;`

#### Insert comment

`insert into a values (4,"hello.html","New Comment");`

You need to provide values for the other two columns along with the new comment.